# bin/sh script to launch during android boot

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, busybox

I have a shell script which I would like to start it during Android boot.

As the script is under /bin/sh hence needs busybox to start the script.
I have busybox installed in Android /system/bin folder.
In the end of init.goldfish.rc I have added below line:

```
service start_my_script /system/bin/busybox ash /path/to/myscript.sh
    class main
    oneshot
```

But somehow my script does not start during android boot.

I am using Android Icecream-Sandwich flavor.

Comment: Can you start busybox ash <script> from shell successfully?

Comment: I can manually start the script successfully by typing in `$/system/bin/busybox ash /path/to/myscript.sh`, but unfortunately cannot do the same thing on boot up.
What should be the file permission for the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The got executed after I gave 555 root:shell permissions to myscript.sh

I can do it in system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h